# How can I convert to date format (DD MMM YYYY) using the shell?

Tags: shell, awk

I have data in a file where one column is a date column which has date in the following format:

```
2021-05-10T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-05-14T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-05-19T18:25:00.000+0100
```

**Expected output is:**

```
10 MAY 2021
14 MAY 2021
19 MAY 2021
```

**My approach which I've tried:**

```
while -r read line
do
    year=`echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }' `
    month=`echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }' `
    dt=`echo $line | awk '{ print $3 }' `

    v=$dt"-"$month"-"$year
    d=date '`$v' | dd-mm-yyyy
    echo $d
done < /f/filename.txt
```

Comment: I'm sure we've covered this for you before but: a) please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and b) please copy/paste your scripts into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about before posting them here so we don't have to see and explain the issues the tool could tell you about.

Comment: `2021-05-11T01:00:00.000+0100` and `2021-05-10T23:00:00.000-0100` are the same time. Which date do you want output?

Comment: Please note that dates written as `numbers-numbers-numbers` with a dash as a separator should be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` because of ISO 8601. If you want another format, _please_ use something else as a separator, such as a space or a slash.

Comment: What shell? On what platform (incl. version)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a number of syntax and design problems in your attempt.

I don't particularly recommend using the shell for this; the other answers with plain `date` and Awk and Perl etc solutions are definitely better for this particular task, both in terms of usability and readability as well as performance. But there are scenarios where you do want or need to use the shell, and then it's important to understand what the proper syntax looks like.

For the record, then, the shell is perfectly capable of splitting the input line on whitespace, or whatever `IFS` is set to, into variables.

You also had some peculiar typos in your `d` assignment.  I'm guessing wildly here as to what you actually meant.

```sh
while IFS='-T' read -r year month dt _;
do
    date -d "$year-$month-$dt" +"%d %b %Y"
done < /f/filename.txt
```

`d=date whatever` would assign the literal string `date` to the variable `d` and then attempt to run `whatever` as a command, and probably fail. But of course, creating a variable only so that you can then immediately `echo` it is just a [useless use of `echo`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

`date -d` is a GNU variation; on *BSD (including macOS) you'd need something like `date -j -f %Y-%m-%d +"%d %b %Y" 2021-05-28`

I don't think `strftime` offers an uppercase version of the month name; if SHOUTING is important to you, maybe pipe to

```
done <file | tr a-z A-Z
```

The format code `%b` is locale-dependent; if you want to force English (or legacy) month names, try `LC_TIME=POSIX date` (notice now how we use the syntax I explained above!)

Answer (score 28):

The GNU coreutils `date` command supports the input format you have, e.g.:

```
date -f filename.txt +'%d %b %Y'
```

Output:

```
10 May 2021
14 May 2021
19 May 2021
```

Pipe it through `tr a-z A-Z` if you want it in all-caps.

Note: tested with version 8.30 of GNU coreutils.

Comment: I like your solution can you make above command generic .. my file as 4 columns NAME | DATE | CITY|COURSE  -> so date will be coming in second column where in that case without  disturbing other columns  i want to format date column data

Comment: @codeholic24: it can be done with e.g. `paste` and `cut`. However, that should probably be asked in a new question with accurate input data

Answer (score 12):

With your sample, please try the following:

```
awk -F'[T-]' '
BEGIN{
  num=split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec",month,",")
}
{
  mon=substr($2,2,1)
}
(mon in month){
  print $3,month[mon],$1
}
' Input_file
```

OR try following:

```
awk -F'[T-]' '
BEGIN{
  num=split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec",month,",")
}
($2+0 in month){
  print $3,month[$2+0],$1
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for the code above:

```
awk -F'[T-]' '             ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as - OR T here for all Lines.
BEGIN{                     ##Starting BEGIN section of this program here.
  num=split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec",month,",") ##Creating month array here which has month names here.
}
{
  mon=substr($2,2,1)       ##Creating variable mon, which has sub string of 2nd field with 1st character.
}
(mon in month){            ##Checking if mon is present in month then do following.
  print $3,month[mon],$1   ##Printing 3rd field, month value 1st field.
}
' Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `gnu-awk`, this can be done in a single line:

```sh
awk '{
print toupper(strftime("%d %b %Y", mktime(gensub(/[-:T]/, " ", "g"))))
}' file

10 MAY 2021
14 MAY 2021
19 MAY 2021
```

Or without `gensub`:

```sh
awk -F '[-:T]' '{$1=$1; print toupper(strftime("%d %b %Y", mktime($0)))}' file
```

Answer (score 8):

Another approach:

```
awk -F'[T-]' 'BEGIN{                         
                mon="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"

              # if need uppercase use below variable
              # mon="JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"
              }
              {
                print $3,substr(mon,($2*3)-2,3), $1
              }' file
```

Test Results:

Input:

```
$ cat file 
2021-01-10T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-02-14T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-03-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-04-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-05-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-06-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-07-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-08-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-09-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-10-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-11-19T18:25:00.000+0100
2021-12-19T18:25:00.000+0100
```

Output :

```
$ awk -F'[T-]' 'BEGIN{mon="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec"}{print $3,substr(mon,($2*3)-2,3), $1}' file
10 Jan 2021
14 Feb 2021
19 Mar 2021
19 Apr 2021
19 May 2021
19 Jun 2021
19 Jul 2021
19 Aug 2021
19 Sep 2021
19 Oct 2021
19 Nov 2021
19 Dec 2021
```

Answer (score 6):

With `perl`:

```sh
$ perl -MTime::Piece -lne '$t = Time::Piece->strptime(substr($_,0,10), "%F");
                           print $t->strftime("%d %b %Y")' ip.txt
10 May 2021
14 May 2021
19 May 2021
```

- `substr($_,0,10)` will give the first 10 characters
- `%F` is equivalent to `%Y-%m-%d`
- `%d %b %Y` required output format
- See https://perldoc.perl.org/Time::Piece for documentation

I used two statements for readability, single statement version shown below:

```sh
perl -MTime::Piece -lne 'print Time::Piece->strptime(substr($_,0,10), "%F")->strftime("%d %b %Y")'
```