# How can I convert to date format (DD MMM YYYY) in file without writing to new file the output

Tags: shell

I have below data in file , In which their is a date column

That should be converted to **expected output** shown below
and output should be replaced in the same file

**Note :** *Output should not be written to another file*

**Data in file**

```
ABC|2021-05-10T18:25:00.000+0100|TYU|ILP
XYZ|2021-05-14T18:25:00.000+0100|IO|JH
VBNM|2021-05-19T18:25:00.000+0100|KL|KJ
```

**I tried this code working fine when file as only one column with date records**: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67734730/how-can-i-convert-to-date-format-dd-mmm-yyyy-using-the-shell)

```
date -f filename.txt +'%d %b %Y'
```

**Expected Output :**

```
ABC|10 MAY 2021|TYU|ILP
XYZ|14 MAY 2021|IO|JH
VBNM|19 MAY 2021|KL|KJ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
  num=split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec",month,",")
}
{
  split($2,arr,"[-T]")
  $2=arr[3]" "month[arr[2]+0] " "arr[1]
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                    ##Starting BEGIN section of awk program from here.
  FS=OFS="|"                              ##Setting FS and OFS as | here.
                                          ##Creating month array with months names here.
  num=split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec",month,",")
}
{
  split($2,arr,"[-T]")                    ##Splitting 2nd field into arr with delimiter of - or T here.
  $2=arr[3]" "month[arr[2]+0] " "arr[1]   ##Saving arr[3] space month value with index of arr[2] space and value of arr[1] here.
}
1                                         ##printing current line here.
' Input_file                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

[I would use AWK to get the field you want from your data, using a custom delimiter (The | character, which might have to be escaped like |)](https://www.unixtutorial.org/awk-delimiter/), then loop through each line passing in the unformatted date, and printing the formatted date.

Lot of messy bash loops and workarounds involved there. Printing the stuff before and after AWK would be near impossible, but it's a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a way to read line by line in a `while` loop and then split the field with`|`.

```sh
cat filename.txt \
  | while IFS='|' read A B C; do
    echo "$A|$(date -d "$B" +'%d %b %Y')|$C"
  done
```

The third and subsequent columns are all stored in the `$C` variable.